# Wordpress Ajax can't use POST, can't pass object

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to reach wordpress ajax from the admin back office, inside a custom post creation.

I have tried with no result to send a POST request, to which the server answers  : 0, with an error 400.

I have tried to dump the $_REQUEST from amin_ajax.php and it is empty when i use this :

```
 $.ajax({
    url : ajaxUrl,
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
      action : "gMapsLatLong",
      adresse : adresse,
      adresse2 : adresse2,
      code_postal : code_postal,
      ville : ville
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
  });
```

I have tried both with and without serializing the data object, with no result.
When I try to use GET, I can only pass the "action" variable, the others are not present in the request.

In my function.php file, I have put :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_gMapsLatLong', 'gMapsLatLong');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_gMapsLatLong', 'gMapsLatLong');
```

Can anyone see something obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try and error I found two issues :

```
jQuery.ajax({
```

instead of

```
$.post({
```

and my values were undefined due to some silly misconception. 
Thanks for your read !

Answer (score 3):

You have said `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` but the value you pass to `data` is not JSON.

Either don't override the Content-Type header (which would cause PHP to not parse the request body as it doesn't have native support for JSON encoded requests) or pass JSON to `data` (by encoding the JavaScript object using `JSON.stringify`).

If you take the latter approach, then the PHP will need to read the raw request body and parse the JSON explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

When you post `json` to PHP, it won't show up in the `$_POST` global.  If you are wanting to send is as a normal, `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` post, then you should remove the `contentType`, and it will then show up in `$_POST`.  If you do want to post json, then you need to do:

```
$.ajax({
url : ajaxUrl,
type : 'POST',
data : JSON.stringify({
  action : "gMapsLatLong",
  adresse : adresse,
  adresse2 : adresse2,
  code_postal : code_postal,
  ville : ville
}),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
});
```

And then in PHP you can do:

```
$_JSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, sadly I am still getting a 400;
Could this have something to do with me being on localhost with wamp?